# SQL Query returning Max and Min of each column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H
------------------------------
8   7   8   10  6   5   7   10
9   9   9   10  8   7   9   9
10  9   8   6   6   9   6   6
10  9   8   7   7   7   9   8
```

And I need a query that returns the maximum and minimum of each column, like this:

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H
------------------------------
8   7   8   6   6   5   6   6
10  9   9   10  8   9   9   10
```

I'm pretty new on SQL, and I'm stuck here.

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far even thought it might not work. Assignments without any attempts are not welcome here.

Comment: This link might be useful: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_min.asp

Comment: I'll keep this in mind next time, Ram. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, this query should help you:

```
select MIN(A), MIN (B), MIN (C), MIN (D), MIN (E), MIN (F), MIN (G), MIN (H)
from yourTable
union all
select MAX(A), MAX (B), MAX (C), MAX (D), MAX (E), MAX (F), MAX (G), MAX (H)
from yourTable
```